# "selected for" or "selected"

Tags: grammar

Which of the following sentence is correct:

"Evolution selected **for** altruism because altruism promotes group cooperation"

or

"Evolution selected altruism because altruism promotes group cooperation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrasal verb 'select **for**' is used in connection with genetics, breeding of plants and animals, etc. In a breeding program, we may wish to produce organisms with particular characteristics or traits. For example, if I wish to produce a new breed of grey cats, I might allow cats to reproduce and only keep grey kittens for further breeding. In this way I could end up with a breed of cats where all or most of the offspring are grey. I have been **selecting for** grey colour. Likewise, scientists, farmers, etc, in breeding animals or plants can select for desired properties (e.g. size, flavour, resistance to disease).

In your first sentence, it is stated that evolution resulted in such a process that favoured altruism.

To say, as your second sentence does, that 'evolution selected altruism' is to state a similar idea but not using breeders' jargon. You could say that 'evolution **favoured** altruism'.